# Существует ли .NET Standard библиотека для парсинга email сообщений?

Tags: c#, email, вёрстка-email, .net-standard

Подскажите, пожалуйста, библиотеку .NET Standard 2.0, которая поможет распарсить тело email-сообщения (строку или массив байтов), или поделитесь собственной реализацией такого класса.

Comment: А как вы получаете это сообщение и в каком оно виде? На сколько я знаю, там раньше использовался банальный HTML код.

Comment: Напрямую с IMAP-сервера читаю, с помощью команд протокола.  Нужно разложить по полочкам текст сообщения, поля Subject, From, To и т.д. Очень не хочется заниматься парсингом вручную.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Библиотека [MimeKit](http://www.mimekit.net)(версия >= 2.0.3 поддерживает .Net Standart 2.0) умеет парсить email-сообщение из потока байт. [Пример](http://www.mimekit.net/docs/html/Parsing-Messages.htm)

```
// Load a MimeMessage from a stream
var message = MimeMessage.Load (stream);
```

На выходе получаем объект типа [MimeMessage](http://www.mimekit.net/docs/html/T_MimeKit_MimeMessage.htm), который содержит соответствующие свойства сообщения.

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите реализацию этой открытой библиотеки, хотя и устарела но смысл раскрывает полностью https://github.com/foens/hpop/tree/master/OpenPop